# Combine lists inside of lists python

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x, multidimensional-array

I am looking for a way to turn this:

`[['a','b'],['c','d'],['e','f']]`

Into this:

`'ab\ncd\nef'`

So that when it is printed out it will look like:

```
ab
cd
ef
```

Comment: `"\n".join("".join(s) for s in [['a','b'],['c','d'],['e','f']])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
list_ = [['a','b'],['c','d'],['e','f']]
'\n'.join([''.join(l) for l in list_])
```

Comment: Regarding your comment (which seems now deleted): If you want the elements in the sublist be seperated by comma, just replace `''.join(l)` by `','.join(l)`

Answer (score 1):

Here you go for a harder way :

```
x = [['a','b'],['c','d'],['e','f']]
string = ''
for i in x:
    for e in i:
        string+=e
    string+="\n"

print string
```

however, "\n".join() also works